# UIPopoverController can't handle ui elements

Tags: ios, uipopovercontroller

Thats how I present my popover

```
- (IBAction)openImage:(id)sender {

        OptionViewController *option = [[OptionViewController alloc] init];
        option.delegate = self;

        if (!popoverController) {
            popoverController = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:option];
        }
        popoverController.delegate = self;
        [popoverController setPopoverContentSize:CGSizeMake(320, 88)];
        [popoverController presentPopoverFromRect:((UIButton *)sender).bounds inView:sender permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];

}
```

There is option view controller

```
#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return 2;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] ;
    }

    NSInteger section = [indexPath row];

    switch (section) {
        case 0: // First cell in section 0
            cell.textLabel.text = @"From library";
            break;
        case 1: // Second cell in section 1
            cell.textLabel.text = @"Make a photo";
            break;
        default:
            // Do something else here if a cell other than 1,2,3 or 4 is requested
            break;
    }
    return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
// I set breakpoints there. For now it doesn't work.
}
```

OptionViewController is a UITableViewController (inherit) that contain UITableView with delegate and datasourse = self (for OptionViewController instance)

I also using XIB. In the XIB UITableView auto-resizing mask setups for each side (left, top, right, bottom)

in other method I don't invoke any additional method that can lock my view or other my actions.

There is a screenshot with a Color offscreen render option

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "I can't handle any UI controls?"

Comment: for example if I tap on buttons they don't work. or when I tap on cell in table. any reaction for me. as if I setup user interaction enabled = false or setEnabled:NO

Comment: Can you post the code that you expect to execute when you tap a cell in the table (from the `PrintViewController` class)? Can you also provide some more information about your view setup - are you using xibs or storyboards? Do you have the appropriate outlets connected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have set the delegate of OptionViewController incorrectly.
If implementation of delegate methods are in OptionViewController then you should remove setting option.delegate or set it to itself: `option.delegate = option;`.

Your dataSource delegate (option.dataSource) looks to be working but not the delegate (option.delegate).

Comment: If I'm wrong then please specify in what files/classes are each parts of code.